# Can I check if an object is kind of a specific class, in PHP?

Tags: php

Example: A method is supposed to return an instance of a SpecificClass. How can I check that return value if it is from that class?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the [`instanceof`](http://www.php.net/instanceof) operator, to check if an object is an instance of :

- A class
- Or a child class of that class
- Or an instance of a class that implements an interface

Which means that it cannot be used to detect if your object is an instance of a `specific` class -- as it will say "yes" if your object is an instance of a child-class of that class.

For instance, this portion of code :

```
class ClassA {}
class ClassB extends ClassA {}

$a = new ClassB();
if ($a instanceof ClassA) {
    echo '$a is an instanceof ClassA<br />';
}
if ($a instanceof ClassB) {
    echo '$a is an instanceof ClassB<br />';
}
```

Will get you this output :

```
$a is an instanceof ClassA
$a is an instanceof ClassB
```

`$a`, in a way, is an instance of `ClassA`, as `ClassB` is a child-class of `ClassA`.

And, of course, `$a` is also an instance of `ClassB` -- see the line where it's instanciated.

Comment: This is also the expected behaviour for anyone familiar with the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)! An instance of ClassB is indeed also an instance of Class A (unless you are doing something very wrong with your OOP).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `instanceof` operator or the [is_a](http://php.net/is_a) function.

`is_a` is useful if you want to pass in a string with the name of the class (in a more dynamic codebase).

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($object instanceof classname)
 ....
```

[Manual: Classes and Objects in PHP5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 5):

You can't check the return value itself, but you can check the class that it's returned from using '[instanceof](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)'. (On a similar basis, you may find '[get_class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)' useful.)