# Laravel: find out if variable is collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I want to find out if a variable is a collection.

I can't use is_object() because it will be true even if it is not an collection.
For now I use this, and it works:

```
if(is_object($images) && get_class($images) != 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection') {
```

But I think it's so ugly that I spend time asking you about another solution.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I would extract it to a helper function isCollection() and use it whenever needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I check if an object is kind of a specific class, in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965722/can-i-check-if-an-object-is-kind-of-a-specific-class-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Check for a Specific Type of Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091143/how-to-check-for-a-specific-type-of-object-in-php)

Comment: May I ask why you need that..Maybe what you need is just..if($images != null)...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
if(is_a($images, 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection')) {
    ....do whatever for a collection....
} else {
    ....do whatever for not a collection....
}
```

Or

```
if ($images instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) {
    ....do whatever for a collection....
}
```

Comment: `is_a` has been deprecated since PHP 5.0, so while it's working, it's not the best advice.

Comment: Strange. It still lists it in PHP 7 according to this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

It does list it as deprecated. My bad.

Comment: @Bogdan `is_a` was deprecated in 5.0.0, but was reinstated (no longer deprecated) as of 5.3.0. However, given the history, I would still recommend `instanceof` over `is_a`. Plus, it reads a little better IMHO.

Comment: Whoops, my bad :). Thanks @patricus.

Comment: Just to note that as it was in my case, I had to remove the quotes on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` for it to work

Comment: Note: I had to use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection (with a leading back-slash)...

Comment: FYI, if what you're trying to achieve is to obtain a Collection from whatever input type, you can also use `collect($variable)` directly since that will convert pretty much anything into a Collection.

Answer (score 51):

The class being used is incorrect here.
In a general sense, you should be testing for the base class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

....
if($images instanceof Collection) { 
 ....
}
```

Comment: I have tried is_array, is_collection and others, but it seems only this way works the best!

Comment: @EddyGoh there's no built-in PHP function called `is_collection`! Btw, Laravel collections look like arrays but they are not, so if you run `is_array` against a Laravel collection will always return `false`.

Comment: yes dear above is not working for me and this worked successfully.

Answer (score 6):

```php
function is_collection($param): bool
{
    return (bool) (($param instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection) || ($param instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection));
}
```

If you are using it a lot you might just want to make function for it.

Combination of @Konchog & @Jonathan Ma answer.

Comment: \Illuminate\Support\Collection provides the 'contract' (interface) for all Collections - it's not really a base class. When we are coding, it's always best to use the most general solution when developing functions, because we can re-use the code in more places. Also, since Db\Elo\Coll. is a specialisation of Supp\Coll, your function is not really necessary.  The point I am making is, if you need to test for Db (because your function/method depends upon a specialisation eg, loadMissingRelation(), then you should test for Db\Elo\Coll. Otherwise - just use the interface.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as Collection;` and then to check it's `$thePossibleCollection instanceof Collection`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Konchong points this out, but I want to make a difference explicit for others.

There is a difference between `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, the base class used by many types of collections in Laravel, and `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, which extends the base class but has additional functionality and within its code, aliases the base class as BaseCollection. This is what you get when you execute a query builder, through a model class and a function like **get()**. An ordinary collection is made with `collect(["my", "array"])` instead.

Note that both classes results in a different set of methods. For example, **load**, **loadMissingRelation**, and a number of other methods are present in the subclass that are not present in the parent class. Inside of the methods in the database subclass however, are a number of escape-hatch if statements that ensure that if someone accidentally uses the subclass when they mean the base class in an unintended fashion (such as adding an element to the collection), the collection will not break.

Note that the following is **true**:

```
User::get() instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
User::get() instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection;
collect(["hello", "i", "am", "a", "base", "collection"]) instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

Note that the following is **false**:

```
collect(["hello im a", "base collection"]) instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
is_array(collect(["hello im a", "base collection"]));
```

Be mindful that while a collection is essentially a wrapper around an array and with very powerful methods, it is not an array and can often fail or throw exceptions in the standard php array functions.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to correct an error I ran into on this answer.

Note that `instanceof` excepts either a (obj) or the name of the class without quotes

```
$images instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
```

Also, interestingly enough there is a speed/performance difference using `instanceof` over `is_a`, but this is probably not relevant for you if you are like me and were searching for an answer to this question in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

For me using is_countable worked:

```
if(is_countable($somethingCountable)) {
// do something with array
} else {
// print something else
```

}

[Read more about is_countable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php)

Comment: `is_countable()` works with laravel `Collection` but it doesn't guarantee that the variable is a `Collection` instance. In fact if $somethingCountable is an array or another object that implements `Countable` it will return `true`.

Comment: it's not the answer that the questioner is looking for.