# PHP: Restrict class type in function parameter

Tags: php, static-typing, function-parameter

I have inherited some code like this

```
    public static function instanciateRepository( $repositoryClass, ... ) {
...
        new $repositoryClass( ... );
    }
```

Where `$repositoryClass` is a class type that needs to be instanciated.

I want to add a syntax check for passing a wrong class argument to this function, specifically limit `$repositoryClass` to sublasses of `CommonRepository`.
Is there a syntax construction to achieve that in PHP, e.g. `instanciateRepository( CommonRepository::class $repositoryClass, ..`?

Comment: Which version are you using? 

You can simply restrict parameter type like this:

`import CommonRepository // import from specific location.`

and next

`public static function instanciateRepository( CommonRepository $repositoryClass, ... )`

Comment: That would mean the parameter is instance of a class, while I need to pass a class type here. @OliwerLisek PHP version is 7.4

Comment: Why you need literally inject a class, not an instance of class? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @OliwerLisek The legacy code uses it to instantiate a new instance of that class.

Comment: It would help if you were a bit more clear about exactly what `$repositoryClass` argument is and what you are trying to do with it. But you can use [instanceof](https://www.php.net/instanceof) to check if your instantiated class conforms to a particular type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965730/11061164

Comment: @mark_b that will be already too late. I want this check to happen statically in IDE

Answer (score 0):

Start off with an `interface` that defines the common methods

```php
interface CommonRepositoryInterface {}
```

Your `CommonRepository` class should be an `abstract` class that implements the interface and common methods

```php
abstract class CommonRepository implements CommonRepositoryInterface {}
```

Now your repository classes can extend the `CommonRepository` but still implement the interface

```php
final class RepositoryClass extends CommonRepository {}
```

Finally your function can take the interface as an argument so that any class instantiations passed in must be of that type

```php
public static function instanciateRepository(CommonRepositoryInterface $repositoryClass, ... ) {}
```

Comment: That would mean the parameter is instance of a class, while I need to pass a class type here